# Spring security with annotations: separated paths (multiply entry points)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm using Spring Boot with annotations and Spring Security.

I need to implement two different kind of authentication:

1. ProviderApiAuthenticationProvider **only** for "/providerrpc" and "/api/(system|provider|drm)/"
2. TestAuthFilter (Custom authentificator, now empty), **only** for "/test/**"

In current configuration on **both** URL's app requests httpBasic authentification and TestAuthFilter::doFilter() also called on both URL's.
So, whats wrong?

**WebSecurityConfig.java:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final ProviderApiAuthenticationProvider providerApiAuthenticationProvider;

    private final TestAuthFilter testAuthFilter;

    @Autowired
    public WebSecurityConfig(TestAuthFilter testAuthFilter, ProviderApiAuthenticationProvider providerApiAuthenticationProvider) {
        this.testAuthFilter = testAuthFilter;
        this.providerApiAuthenticationProvider = providerApiAuthenticationProvider;
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(providerApiAuthenticationProvider);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("SpellCheckingInspection")
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authenticationProvider(providerApiAuthenticationProvider)
            .authorizeRequests()
                .regexMatchers(
                        "^/providerrpc/",
                        "^/api/(system|provider|drm)/"
                )
                .hasAuthority(Role.ROLE_PROVIDER_API.getAuthority())
                .and()
                .httpBasic()
                .realmName("Provider API")
        .and()
            .addFilterBefore(testAuthFilter, BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(
                        "/test/**"
                )
                .authenticated()
        .anyRequest()
        .permitAll()
        ;
    }
}
```

**TestAuthFilter.java:**

```
@Component
public class TestAuthFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        // TODO: Later implement via SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication();

        chain.doFilter(request,response);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, what is wrong?  You actually do not state what problem are you having.  You might want to edit the question with what you want to achieve and why your code is not achieving that.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution which provides two independent entry points for authentication in the official documentation: [Spring Security: 5.7 Multiple HttpSecurity](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#multiple-httpsecurity)

Here is the solution:

**MultiHttpSecurityConfig.java**

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class MultiHttpSecurityConfig {

    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    public static class RestApiWebSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                .antMatcher("/api/rest/**")
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().hasAuthority(Role.ROLE_USER.getAuthority())
                .and()
                .httpBasic()
                .realmName("Rest API")
                .and().csrf().disable()
                ;
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(2)
    public static class TestWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                .antMatcher("/test**")
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic()
                .realmName("Test zone");
        }
    }
}
```